# To get data from gyroscope of a windows phone emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am making a windows phone app in which pages will change or rotating the phone so I just can't find out how to use the gyroscopic data as trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can't emulate the gyroscope in the emulator:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629629.aspx

You can organize your code to insulate the part reading the data and create some Mock class feeding dummy data for the debug pourposes.